# Uploading to Amazon S3 via curl route

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up a file upload REST API via Spring Boot.

I currently have a list/GET method `curl http://localhost:8080/api/aws/s3/list` which returns a list of objects that currently exist in the bucket.

For upload, I have been trying:

```
curl -F "data=@test.txt" http://localhost:8080/api/aws/s3/upload -i
```

Which produces:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2017 23:28:36 GMT
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But when I look at the bucket, it hasn't been updated with the new file.

Would this be a permissions issue on AWS? Only my account has read and write access. The user and group I created have admin privileges. I didn't add a Bucket Policy. This is my CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here is the upload section of my S3 Controller in spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<PutObjectResult> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
    return s3Wrapper.upload(multipartFiles);
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should specify your using bucket name and some parameters for S3. And I guess it's PUT, not POST. There are several command line samples in the internet.

```
file=/path/to/file/to/upload.tar.gz
bucket=your-bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

- [Uploading to S3 in 18 lines of Shell (used to upload builds for http://soltrader.net)](https://gist.github.com/chrismdp/6c6b6c825b07f680e710)
- [Uploading to S3 in Bash](http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash)

Comment: Make sure you use /bin/echo instead of just echo.  That one trapped me.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153660/why-echo-help-doesnt-give-me-help-page-of-echo

Comment: I think this Authorization method is no longer supported, you have to use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Comment: doesn't work
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: @sale108  https://gist.github.com/mmaday/c82743b1683ce4d27bfa6615b3ba2332

Answer (score 7):

```
    #run this code on ec2 linux with s3 write role 

TOKEN=`curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
xamztoken=`curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ec2files3 | jq -r ".Token"`


yyyymmdd=`date +%Y%m%d`
s3Bucket="testfiles3bc"
bucketLocation="us-east-1"
s3SecretKey=`curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ec2files3 | jq -r '.SecretAccessKey'`
s3AccessKey=`curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN"  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ec2files3 | jq -r ".AccessKeyId"`
endpoint="testfiles3bc.s3.amazonaws.com"
fileName="image.gif"
contentLength=`cat ${fileName} | wc -c`
contentHash=`openssl sha -sha256 -hex ${fileName} | sed 's/.* //'`
contentType=`file -b --mime-type $fileName`
b64=`openssl md5 -binary "$fileName" | openssl base64`
acl="private"

date=`date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ`

expdate_s="2022-12-30T12:00:00.000Z"

region="us-east-1"


p=$(cat <<POLICY | openssl base64 | tr -d \\n
{ "expiration": "${expdate_s}T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "$acl" },
    {"bucket": "$s3Bucket" },
    ["starts-with", "\$key", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$contentType", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-date": "$date" },
    {"content-md5": "$b64" },
    {"x-amz-credential": "${s3AccessKey}/${yyyymmdd}/${region}/s3/aws4_request" },
    {"x-amz-security-token": "${xamztoken}" },
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" }
  ]
}
POLICY
)


stringToSign=$p
echo "----------------- canonicalRequest --------------------"
echo -e ${canonicalRequest}
echo "----------------- stringToSign --------------------"
echo -e ${stringToSign}
echo "-------------------------------------------------------"



# calculate the signing key
DateKey=`echo -n "${yyyymmdd}" | openssl sha -sha256 -hex -hmac "AWS4${s3SecretKey}" | sed 's/.* //'`
DateRegionKey=`echo -n "${bucketLocation}" | openssl sha -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
DateRegionServiceKey=`echo -n "s3" | openssl sha -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateRegionKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
SigningKey=`echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl sha -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateRegionServiceKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
# then, once more a HMAC for the signature
signature=`echo -en ${p} | openssl sha -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${SigningKey} | sed 's/.* //'`


key_and_sig_args="-F X-Amz-Credential=${s3AccessKey}/${yyyymmdd}/${region}/s3/aws4_request -F X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F X-Amz-Signature=$signature -F X-Amz-Date=${date}"


curl -v   \
-F key=$fileName \
-F acl=$acl \
$key_and_sig_args  \
-F "content-md5= ${b64}" \
-F "Policy=$p" \
-F "X-Amz-Security-Token= ${xamztoken}" \
-F "file=@$fileName" \
https://${s3Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a curl version >= 7.75.0 you can add files to s3 like this

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$1

S3_ACCESS_KEY="<ACCESS_KEY>"
S3_SECRET_KEY="<SECRET_KEY>"
S3_BUCKET="<BUCKET_NAME>"
S3_REGION="<REGION>"

curl --progress-bar -X PUT \
    --user "${S3_ACCESS_KEY}":"${S3_SECRET_KEY}" \
    --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:${S3_REGION}:s3" \
    --upload-file ${FILE} \
    https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.${S3_REGION}.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because the parameter I set in my controller was `file` but in my curl route I kept using `data`