# Upload to aws s3 file via curl

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a report to a aws s3 server and im the soluctions I have found aren't working I keep getting either a sha264 error or The authorization header is malformed. I'm clueless regarding sh and doing a post in curl and files and on how to upload. Also after uploading I need to generate a download link. Also this sh is to be run on jenkins.

This is one of the solutions I looked into:

- [s3 bash upload](https://gist.github.com/tabolario/93f24c6feefe353e14bd)
- [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751574/uploading-to-amazon-s3-via-curl-route), is invalid since the authorization mechanism isn't supported anymore.

Below is the error I get:

```
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the authorization component "Signature=" is malformed.</Message><RequestId>182183F5B97F9258</RequestId><HostId>s3MwGZUpioyk+3Qfj0q51LqY4iosCEC84xThxscQFPwX4SbvJk66oi4qIyEaVkdNLUGL1CciXlY=</HostId></Error>%
```

Comment: why not using `s3cmd` or `aws` command ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot because this runs on a jenkins server which i don't have control over

Comment: The solution provide in the posible duplicate is that it's outdated when you run the script it tells you to use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 as authorization mechanism

Comment: You can set a jenkins shell command that download `s3cmd` then run it on your bucket !

Comment: They dont want me to install anything extra on the build.

Answer (score 3):

Better use a proper command, [s3cmd](/questions/tagged/s3cmd) :

Check http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

(the right tool for the right job...)

Or [the `aws` command](http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/AutoScaling-2011-01-01.zip) :

```
aws s3 sync /tmp/foo s3://bucket/
```

Comment: Small note: The AWS command for a file is `cp`