# How to generate an aws4 signed request in bash?

Tags: bash, http, authentication, amazon-s3

I'm trying to connect to the Scaleway S3 api in bash (it's a [subset](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/s3-object-operations/#-PUT-Object) of aws s3 api). The signature model is aws4_request, and is [documented](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/s3-generate-awsv4-signature/). In the code below I'm uploading a file. I've reviewed every line and although I'm no bash guru, I'm pretty confident I have all the right parts to compute a correct signature, but I still get 403 error as a response. The request itself seems fine, as far as I can see in a wireshark capture. Can anyone find any issue here?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

    echo "creds $SCW_ACCESS_KEY/$SCW_SECRET_KEY"

    BUCKET="vni-backups"
    REGION="fr-par"
    HOST="$BUCKET.s3.$REGION.scw.cloud"

    filepath="../import.yml"
    file_sha256=$(sha256sum -b $filepath | head -c64)

    fulldate=$(date +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ" --utc)
    shortdate=$(date +"%Y%m%d" --utc)

    # Assemble canonical url
    canonicalRequest="PUT
    /import.yml

    content-type:text/plain
    host:$HOST
    x-amz-content-sha256:$file_sha256
    x-amz-date:$fulldate
    content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
    $file_sha256"

    canonReqSha=$(echo -n "$canonicalRequest" | openssl dgst -sha256 | awk '{print $2}')

    echo $canonicalRequest
    echo "requestHash: $canonReqSha"

    echo "
    ---------------------------------------
    "

    stringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
    $fulldate
    $shortdate/fr-par/s3/aws4_request
    $canonReqSha"

    echo $stringToSign

    dateKey=$(echo -n "$shortdate" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "AWS4$SCW_SECRET_KEY")
    regionKey=$(echo -n "fr-par" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "$dateKey")
    serviceKey=$(echo -n "s3" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "$regionKey")
    signingKey=$(echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "$serviceKey")

    signature=$(echo -n "$stringToSign" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$signingKey" | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "signature: $signature"


    echo "
    ---------------------------------------
    "
    # Make request

    curl -X PUT \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     -H "x-amz-content-sha256: $file_sha256" \
     -H "x-amz-date: $fulldate" \
     -H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" \
     -H "Credential: $SCW_ACCESS_KEY/${shortdate}/$REGION/s3/aws4_request" \
     -H "SignedHeaders: content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date" \
     -H "Signature: $signature" \
     --data-binary @../import.yml \
     "http://$BUCKET.s3.$REGION.scw.cloud/import.yml"
```

The request is done in clear http just because it's simpler to capture it with network analysis tool (e.g. wireshark) than https.

Comment: Have you tried using `awscli` with `--endpoint` to point to Scaleway instead of crafting signatures manually?

Comment: @jordanm I intend to use it on a machine that's quite limited on disk space, and I'd rather do it this way than installing hundreds of Mbs to sign 1 request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751574/uploading-to-amazon-s3-via-curl-route/65096396#65096396 solved my issue, just adapted it from s3 to scaleway endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I have struggled hours and hours with the exact same issue and I finally cracked it. The issue in your code above is the chaining sequence of signature using `hmac` and `binary`. Here is my Bash version which works:

Specific header rules:

- `x-amz-content-sha256` Is to be included if the service is `s3` or if there is a body provided with the request
- `content-type` Must be included if it is part of the request
- All headers starting in `x-amz` necessary to an api request must be included

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCESS_KEY="XXX"
SECRET_KEY="XXXX"

REGION="us-east-1"
SERVICE="sns"
METHOD="GET"
HOST="$SERVICE.$REGION.amazonaws.com"
ALGO="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"

fulldate=$(date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M00Z")
shortdate=$(date -u +"%Y%m%d")


file_sha256=$(echo -n "" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | xxd -p -c 256)

function urlencode() {
  local length="${#1}"
  for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
    local c="${1:i:1}"
    case $c in
      [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
    *) printf "$c" | xxd -p -c1 | while read x;do printf "%%%s" "$x";done
  esac
done
}

function to_hex() {
    printf "$1" | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d [:space:]
}
function hmac_sha256() {
    printf "$2" | \
        openssl dgst -binary -hex -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:"$1" | \
        sed 's/^.* //'
}

canonicalQuery = "$(urlencode "Action")=$(urlencode "ListSubscriptions")"

# Assemble canonical url
canonicalRequest="$METHOD
/
$canonicalQuery
host:$HOST
x-amz-date:$fulldate

host;x-amz-date
$file_sha256"

canonReqSha=$(echo -n "$canonicalRequest" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | xxd -p -c 256)

stringToSign="$ALGO
$fulldate
$shortdate/$REGION/$SERVICE/aws4_request
$canonReqSha"

secret=$(to_hex "AWS4${SECRET_KEY}")
k_date=$(hmac_sha256 "${secret}" "${shortdate}")
k_region=$(hmac_sha256 "${k_date}" "${REGION}")
k_service=$(hmac_sha256 "${k_region}" "${SERVICE}")
k_signing=$(hmac_sha256 "${k_service}" "aws4_request")
signature=$(hmac_sha256 "${k_signing}" "${stringToSign}" | sed 's/^.* //')


AUTHORIZATION="$ALGO Credential=$ACCESS_KEY/$shortdate/$REGION/$SERVICE/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=$signature"

curl -X $METHOD \
  -H "X-Amz-Date:$fulldate" \
  -H "Authorization:$AUTHORIZATION" \
  "http://$HOST/?$canonicalQuery"
```